# How to track Facebook posts we shared through email?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-fql

We will send a email to targeted users

Email contains a link name *Share via Facebook*

When targeted users clicks on the Link

It will open face book page asking them to share the post

If the targeted users share the post as public, How we should track them?

Who ever likes the post How we should track them?

How many users like the post, How we should track them?

In my above questions all are feasible? If yes how can we do that, any links helping the same?

Comment: please be more specific and add what you have tried so far (research+code). although, in general i would say it is not possible at all.

Comment: Before proceed further we went through several forums like Facebook Developer forum and stack over flow for the related queries, Got the same doubt whether it's feasible or not? Hence Posted the same query. Thanks for the reply